# Is there a script I can run to remove all the hard (carriage) returns in a .txt file?

Tags: macos, automation, terminal, applescript

I have a .txt (Mac OS X Snow Leopard) file that has a lot of text. At the end of a paragraph, there is a hard return that moves the next paragraph onto another line. This is causing some issues with what I am wanting to do to get the content into my db, so I am wondering if there is anyway I can remove the hard returns? Is there some sort of script I can run? I am really hoping I don't have to go through and manually take the hard returns out.

To recap, here is what it looks like now:

```
This is some text. Text is what this is.
And then this is the next paragraph that is on a different line.
```

And this is what I would like to get to:

```
This is some text. Text is what this is. And then this is the next paragraph that is on a different line.
```

For all several thousand lines in my .txt file.

Thanks!

EDIT:

The text I am dealing with in my txt file is actually HTML:

```
<a href="/link/link/1"> <span class="text">1 </span> THis is where my text is</a><br/>
```

And when I run the cat command in terminal like mentioned below, only the first  is there. Everything else is missing...

Comment: It should no work only with first file!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally just use an editor with good Regular Expression support. TextWrangler is great.

An *end of line* in TextWrangler is `\r`, so to remove it, just search for `\r` and replace it with a space. TBH, I always wondered how it handles CRLF-encoded files, but somehow it works.

Comment: Thanks Monolo, would you mind sharing with my a regex that could work for this scenario? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal:

```
cat myfile.txt | tr -d '\r' > file2.txt
```

There's probably a more efficient way to do this, since the "tr -d '\r'" is the active ingredient, but that's the idea.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I tried it and it is saying 'tr: Illegal byte sequence'. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because tr's support for unicode is lacking. That is, in the sense it doesn't exist. Try `sed "/\r/d" myfile.txt > file2.txt` and see if that works. If it does, you have a winner for sure, but I don't know if sed supports unicode either.

Comment: Hmm, it makes the new file, but it doesn't have anything in it...darn

Comment: Okay, how about `sed -e '/\r?\n/d' myfile.txt > file2.txt` ? And if that works, you can use the -i option to do substitution within the same file, I just don't want to recommend that until the regex works as expected because then you lose your file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with Applescript. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with it however the following should help you to acomplish this (it's for a different problem but it will lead you in the direction you need to go): http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=18762

Alternatively if you didn't want to do this with Applescript and have Excel installed (or access to a machine with it) then the following should help: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=474054

Answer (score 1):

In Linux terminal `cat file.txt | tr -d "\r\n" | > new file.txt` will do. Modify `\r\n` part to remove desired charters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have clarified that I am dealing with HTML in my txt file. Your command only saved the first <a tag into the new file. Please see my edit. Thanks!